# Shelosha Veshiv'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred seventy-three?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible.*

*At some undetermined point in the future, at least a day from now, I will:*

- *Vote up all interesting, relevant answers.*
- *Accept what I consider the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

*[Gemar chatima tova](http://www.learnhebrew.org.il/print/gmar.htm), everybody!*

Comment: Hm, any _halachos_ that kick in at 273 Kelvin?

Comment: @msh: sure! For example, that would be the minimum temperature of H2O used for nisuch hamayim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A beis kor (the area in which a kor, about 500-700 lb., of grain can be sown) is defined in halachah as 75000 square cubits. Rashi (to [Kiddushin 60b](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=2747&size=1), ד"ה בית כור) points out that this is a square a bit more than 273 5/6 cubits to a side (and indeed, √75000 ≈ 273.86).

Answer (score 6):

There were 273 more first-born men than *l'viyim* in [*Bamidbar*](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T0403).